# VectorStoreRetrieverMemory doesn't work with AgentExecutor

Tags: py-langchain

I followed the official documents and did all kind of research in the web, but to no avail.

I'm setting up the chat history for langchain, and I'm using the vector backed chat history, which you can see in the docs that it's not much.

I'm implementing VectorStoreRetrieverMemory with AgentExecutor. I did it with MongoDBChatMessageHistory and it works, but not with the vector retriever memory.

I get the following error:

**ValueError: variable history should be a list of base messages, got [Document(page_content="input: Hello i'm Abel Mendonça?\noutput: Hello Abel Mendonça! How can I assist you today?")]**

```
memory = VectorStoreRetrieverMemory(
   retriever=retriever,
   return_messages=True,
   return_docs=True,
  )

tool = create_retriever_tool(
      retriever,
      "search_egypt_mythology",
      "Searches and returns documents about egypt mythology",
  )
  tools = [tool]
  
  system_message = SystemMessage(
      content=(
          "Do your best to answer the questions. "
          "Feel free to use any tools available to look up "
          "relevant information, only if necessary"
      )
  )
  
  prompt = OpenAIFunctionsAgent.create_prompt(
      system_message=system_message,
      extra_prompt_messages=[
          MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history")
      ],
  )
  
  agent = OpenAIFunctionsAgent(llm=__llm, tools=tools, prompt=prompt)

  chat = AgentExecutor(
      agent=agent,
      tools=tools,
      memory=memory,
      verbose=True,
      return_intermediate_steps=True,
  )

result = chat({"input":"my question"})
answer = result['output']
```

Have anybody implemented this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is fully discussed here: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/13516 with the key remediation step being:

To resolve this issue, you could try setting return_docs to True when you instantiate VectorStoreRetrieverMemory, like so:

```
memory = VectorStoreRetrieverMemory(
    retriever=retriever,
    return_messages=True,
    return_docs=True,
)
```